# Оформление прямой речи, состоящей из нескольких отдельных фрагментов

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, однородные-члены, цитата

*Неопытный работник постоянно говорит: «Подождите, я уточню». «В данный момент не могу вам сказать». «Я не уверен».*

*Неопытный работник постоянно говорит: «Подождите, я уточню»; «В данный момент не могу вам сказать»; «Я не уверен».*

И что делать, если такая прямая речь ещё и оказывается внутри слов автора?

*Неопытный работник постоянно говорит: «Подождите, я уточню», «В данный момент не могу вам сказать», «Я не уверен», что обычно сильно раздражает клиентов.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу только один вариант.

***Неопытный работник постоянно говорит: "Подождите, я уточню", "В данный момент не могу вам сказать", "Я не уверен", — что обычно сильно раздражает клиентов.***

Аналогично и без последней части.

Точку с запятой я бы тут не ставил, для неё нет решительно никакой мотивации, тире опционально, остальное - см.  Римма Михайлова.

Comment: Если работник произносит эти фразы по порядку, то подходит вариант с многоточием. Но скорее всего, он произносит то одно то другое, поэтому Ваш вариант верен.

Answer (score 1):

1. Все "маленькие" предложения оформляются как единая прямая речь.

**Неопытный работник постоянно говорит: "Подождите, я уточню. В данный момент не могу вам сказать. Я не уверен", что обычно сильно раздражает клиентов.**

Или:
**Неопытный работник постоянно говорит: "Подождите, я уточню... В данный момент не могу вам сказать... Я не уверен..." — что обычно сильно раздражает клиентов.**

2. Вполне возможно, думаю, и оформление как перечисление:

**Неопытный работник постоянно говорит: "подождите, я уточню"; "в данный момент не могу вам сказать"; "я не уверен", — что обычно сильно раздражает клиентов.**

Т. к. в одном из "маленьких" предложений присутствует запятая, между ними лучше поставить точку с запятой. Но есть сомнение: нужна ли запятая перед тире?

**Дополнение**

**1.** Если прямая речь оказывается внутри слов автора , то она заключается в кавычки, а перед ней ставится двоеточие; прямая речь начинается с прописной буквы.
После прямой речи знаки препинания расставляются следующим образом:

а) запятая ставится, если она была необходима в месте разрыва вводящих слов автора (первое предложение);
в) тире ставится, если прямая речь заканчивается многоточием (второе предложение).
[**Знаки препинания при прямой речи. §136**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85/)

**2.** Если однородные члены предложения, стоящие после обобщающего слова, не заканчивают собой предложения, то перед ними ставится двоеточие, а после — тире.
Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов предложения требуется постановка запятой, то она ставится, а тире или ставится, или опускается.

Я имела в виду такой смысл предложения:
Неопытный работник постоянно говорит [такие слова]...

[**Знаки препинания в предложениях с однородными членами (пункт 8)**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=76)

Comment: По поводу п. 2 сомневаюсь я, однако!

Comment: Не могли бы дать ссылку на правило для «маленьких» предложений.

Comment: А какое из правил Вас интересует: о прямой речи или о перечислении?

Comment: И то, и то. Также по условию контекста правильно перед "что" поставить запятую, а не тире.

Comment: Я дополнила свой ответ.

Comment: Первый ваш вариант не смотрится, ибо возникает ощущение, что все жто говорится как один последовательный текст. Во втором мне не нравится только идея использовать точку с запятой. Все-таки перечисление оформляется с помощью запятых всегда, а та запятая, что внутри кавычек вообще  никак не воздействует на знаки вне их.

Comment: Не могли бы вы дать ссылку на правило, где сказано: «Все "маленькие" предложения оформляются как единая прямая речь»?

Comment: Очень странно, что Вы "приняли" вариант, который является ошибочным: _после прямой речи ставится запятая, если она была необходима в месте разрыва вводящих слов автора._  Ваше предложение без прямой речи: _Неопытный работник постоянно говорит, что обычно сильно раздражает клиентов._ Опциональное тире здесь **никак** не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

В ваших примерах нет прямой речи. Во-первых, не то время. Во-вторых, лицо физически не способно сказать три предложения одновременно. В-третьих, реплика является ответом в диалоге.

Пример прямой речи:

> — У вас есть духовки, — спросил я у продавца.
>   — Подождите, я уточню, — ответил неопытный работник.

Могу предположить, так как точно не уверен, что все высказывания это однородные дополнения. В таком случае предложение должно быть оформлено следующим образом:

> Неопытный работник постоянно говорит: подождите, я уточню; в данный
>   момент не могу вам сказать, я не уверен — что обычно сильно раздражает
>   клиентов.

Comment: Послушайте, но у вас эти фразы говорят **разные** люди. Это диалог. Но прямая речь в исходном примере не перестаёт же быть прямой?!

Comment: Первые фразы и пример в Вашем, Сергей Иваненко, ответе бездоказательны и к вопросу отношения не имеют. Усложнять не надо. Предположение (без оговорок: точно не уверен) нормальное, но, почему-то исключает не только прямую речь, но и цитирование.